# Remove text under desktop icons

Tags: gnome, icons

as the title says I am trying to remove the text under the trash bin icon on the desktop. I googled something about to change the name to "alt + 255" thing is I can't rename this specific icon, then I found something with dconf editor to set the the font to "Ubuntu 0" under `org.gnome.nautilus.desktop` but there is no desktop. I am using Ubuntu 19.10 with the Gnome DE. Can it be that it is not possible in 19.10?

Comment: Hi.. On Desktop Only Trash Bin Visible or your Regular files and Home Folder als0?? What's your case.. When multiple Files exists on Desktop, would you like to remove the text only for Trash Bin.. Workaround depends on the particular case.. Plz mention your case..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/61ivW.jpg

Comment: Hi, yes only the trash bin on the desktop